# numpy dot with more than 2 dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, dot-product

In the numpy `dot(...)` function [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) it is said that:

> If a is an N-D array and b is an M-D array (where M>=2), it is a sum product over the last axis of a and the second-to-last axis of b:
> `dot(a, b)[i,j,k,m] = sum(a[i,j,:] * b[k,:,m])`

This is sensibly different from the `matmul(...)` function, where the matrices product over the last two dimensions is simply broadcasted along the first dimensions (if the matrix has more than 2 dimensions).

However, while it is clear the utility of the matmul behaviour, I wonder what the possible applications are for the result given by `dot(...)` for matrix with more than 2 dimensions. Is there any pratical application where `dot(a, b)[i,j,k,m] = sum(a[i,j,:] * b[k,:,m])` can be useful?

Comment: On top of my head, [Einstein field equation](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/ed40b82aae2918a6e4a83a431da5227daec5786a) looks similar to it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recall any discussions as to why this approach was chosen.  It may just be for ease of calculation.  Its limitations have led to the development of `einsum` and later `matmul`.

```
dot(a, b)[i,j,k,m] = sum(a[i,j,:] * b[k,:,m])
```

einsum equivalent

```
np.einsum('ijl,klm->ijkm', a, b)
```

with a transpose and reshape it can be written as

```
np.einsum('pl,lo', A, B)    # p=ij, o=km
```

`A`,`B` can then be passed to conventional BLAS functions.  That functionality might even be built into BLAS.